# Install gcc3.x on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: gcc

Is there any one who knows how to install gcc3.x on Ubuntu 10.04? The original version is 4.4.3. I downloaded the gcc3.4.1 source code and compiled, but failed. Got the error " error: call to ‘__open_missing_mode’ declared with attribute error: open with O_CREAT in second argument needs 3 arguments ". Is there some arguments I need to set specifically or is there any package to install on 10.04?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 by default, you should add "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" in CFLAGS

Comment: I've verified that this works (and is apparently necessary) for building `gcc-3.4.6` from upstream source on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin.